# Update is not changing fields values on tables

Tags: .net, vb.net, adapter

I'm developing a customization on Epicor with .net. I'm trying to update a table but, I don't know why it doesn't work.. The fields keep containing the same values after I close the app. Is there something I'm missing?? Thanks in advance!

```
Dim adapterLaborDtlSearch As LaborDtlSearchAdapter = New LaborDtlSearchAdapter(HHWorkQueueForm)
adapterLaborDtlSearch.BOConnect()
LaborDtlDV = CType(oTrans.EpiDataViews("LaborDtl"), EpiDataView)
Dim laborHedSeq As Integer = LaborDtlDV.dataView(LaborDtlDV.Row)("laborHedSeq")
Dim laborDtlSeq As Integer = LaborDtlDV.dataView(LaborDtlDV.Row)("laborDtlSeq")
Dim laborDtlSchDataSet As Data.DataSet = adapterLaborDtlSearch.GetData(laborHedSeq, laborDtlSeq)
laborDtlSchDataSet.Tables("LaborDtl").Rows(0).BeginEdit
laborDtlSchDataSet.Tables("LaborDtl").Rows(0).Item("LaborQty") = nedShiftQty.value
laborDtlSchDataSet.Tables("LaborDtl").Rows(0).EndEdit
laborDtlSchDataSet.Tables("LaborDtl").AcceptChanges
adapterLaborDtlSearch.Update()
```

Here is the stacktrace on update method.

```
Exception caught in: Epicor.Mfg.BO.LaborDtlSearch

Error Detail
============
Message: This function is not allowed.
Type: Error
Program: bo/LaborDtlSearch/LaborDtlSearch.p
Method: laborDtlBeforeUpdate
Table: laborDtl
Row: 
Field: 

Stack Trace
===========
   at Epicor.Mfg.Proxy.LaborDtlSearchImpl.Update(LaborDtlSearchDataSet ds)
   at Epicor.Mfg.UI.Adapters.LaborDtlSearchAdapter.Update()
   at Script.updateTablesData()

Inner Exception
===============
ERROR condition: The Server application has returned an error. (7243)  (7211) 

Inner Stack Trace
=================
   at Progress.Open4GL.DynamicAPI.Session.runProcedure(String requestID, String procedureName, ParameterSet parms, Boolean persistent, Boolean internal_Renamed, Int64 procId, MetaSchema localSchema, Int32 stateModel)
   at Progress.Open4GL.DynamicAPI.Session.runStatelessProcedure(String requestID, String fullProcedureName, ParameterSet inparams, Object procId, MetaSchema localSchema, Int32 stateModel)
   at Progress.Open4GL.DynamicAPI.PersistentProc.runTheProcedure(String requestID, String procedureName, ParameterSet parms, MetaSchema schema)
   at Progress.Open4GL.DynamicAPI.PersistentProc.runProcedure(String procedureName, ParameterSet parms, MetaSchema schema)
   at Epicor.Mfg.Core.CallContext.CallContextPersistentProc.runProcedure(String procedureName, ParameterSet parameters, MetaSchema metaSchema)
   at Epicor.Mfg.Core.CallContext.ProxyHelper.CallMethod(String methodName, ParameterSet parameters, MetaSchema metaSchema, BLConnectionPool connPool, Session connection, PersistentProc persistProc, CallContextDataSet callContextDataSet)
   at Epicor.Mfg.Proxy.LaborDtlSearchImpl.Update(LaborDtlSearchDataSet ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the call to `AcceptChanges` after the `adapterLaborDtlSearch.Update()` call.

> When AcceptChanges is called, any DataRow object still in edit mode successfully ends its edits. The DataRowState also changes: **all Added and Modified rows become Unchanged**, and Deleted rows are removed.
>
> The AcceptChanges method is generally called on a DataTable after you attempt to update the DataSet using the DbDataAdapter.Update method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If I move the call of AcceptChanges after adapterLaborDtlSearch.Update() on execution it throws an Error "This function is not allowed"

I've edited the question with the stacktrace thrown.

Can it be something to do with the database that is not allowing updates? Any missing configuration..

Comment: @Marcos: I'm not familiar with Epicor, but it looks like you've got a method which is executing before the table is updated, and that method is causing the error.